Proving $ \cos(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sin\left(3x/2\right)}{\sin\left(x/2\right)} - 1\right)$
$$
LHS = \cos(x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{2\sin(x)} = \frac 1 2\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac 32x\right)\cos\left(\frac 12x\right) + \cos\left(\frac 32x\right)\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)\cos\left(\frac 12x\right)}\right) \\
\frac 1 4\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)} + \frac{\cos\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\cos\left(\frac12x\right)}\right)
$$
really close to the answer, but just can't figure out how to convert cosine part

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I suggest you use the formulae for $sin(3x)$ and $cos(3x)$ to proceed

Continuing,
$$\frac 1 4\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)} + \frac{\cos\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\cos\left(\frac12x\right)}\right)
$$
$$ = \frac{1}{4} \left( 2\frac{\sin\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)} - \frac{\sin\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)} + \frac{\cos\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\cos\left(\frac12x\right)} \right) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{4} \left( 2\frac{\sin\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)} + \frac{\cos\left(\frac 32x\right)\sin\left(\frac 12x\right) - \sin\left(\frac 32x\right)\cos\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)\cos\left(\frac 12x\right)}\right) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{4} \left( 2\frac{\sin\left(\frac 32x\right)}{\sin\left(\frac 12x\right)} + \frac{\sin\left(\frac 12x - \frac 32x \right)}{\frac{1}{2}\sin\left( 2\left( \frac 12x\right) \right)}\right). $$
Can you finish it from here?

How did you come up with this method? It's impossible for me to think of such a technique.

I dunno. Lots of experience and also I just tried something and it happened to lead somewhere. I didn't see the whole method to the end when I got the second line. But I persevered with it and just happened to end up getting to the answer. Also, I'm sure there are easier methods than the one starting in your question.

we have:
$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos\left({\frac{x+y}{2}}\right)\sin\left({\frac{x-y}{2}}\right)$$
Therfore:
$$\cos\left({\frac{x+y}{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left({\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(y)}{\sin\left({\frac{x-y}{2}}\right)}}\right)$$

magic solution.

$$\frac{1}{2}( \frac{3sin(\frac{x}{2})-4sin^3(\frac{x}{2})}{sin(\frac{x}{2}))}-1)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}( {3-4sin^2(\frac{x}{2})}-1)$$
$$\frac{1}{2}( {2-4sin^2(\frac{x}{2})})$$
$$1-2sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$$
Is an alternate way to do it

Note that the two expression are not completely equivalent because RHS is not well defined when $ x  =2k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb Z$.
As an alternative to the very fine methods already suggested, by $x=\pi + 2y$ we obtain
$$\cos(\pi + 2y) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2 +3y\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}2 +y\right)} - 1\right)$$
$$1-2\cos (2y)=\frac{-\cos 3y}{\cos y}$$
$$\cos y \left(1-4\cos^2 y+2\right)=-\cos 3y$$
$$4\cos^2 y-3\cos y =\cos 3y$$
which is true.

By sum-to-product formula, we have
$$
2 \cos x \sin \frac{x}{2}=\sin \frac{3 x}{2}-\sin \frac{x}{2}
$$
Dividing the equation by $2\sin \frac{x}{2} $ yields
$$
\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sin \left(\frac{3 x}{2}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}-1\right)
$$
